# Iframe does not scroll on ios8 ipad

Tags: ipad, iframe, scroll, ios8

I need help making my web site iframe scroll on the ios8 ipad.

https://secure.gymnasticseast.com/4dcgi/1/class_manager.a4d?loc=bellevue

This shows an iframe the slides horizontally, but does not move at all vertically.

I've tried all of the combinations of css, inline styles suggested here to get it to work, but none have yet to scroll vertically on the iPad.

Please help!

Thanks!!

Comment: Please read the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) guidelines: *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."*

Answer (score 0):

In my experience IFrames an Framesets don't work on Safari mobile, there are other solutions that do work depending on the problem.

Follow this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone.html) that confirms that.

Comment: Before I posted this, I followed the advice of another thread here where they solved their same problem as I am now having. Their advice did not work for me. But iFrames have been working on iPads and others are doing it.